# makefile: % pattern in prerequisite $(variable)

Tags: variables, design-patterns, makefile, prerequisites

I have something like this that works:

```
target1.PREREQUISITES = file11 file12 file13
target2.PREREQUISITES = file21 file22 file23

$(myDir)target1.sfx : $(target1.PREREQUISITES)
    <same recipe here>

$(myDir)target2.sfx : $(target2.PREREQUISITES)
    <same recipe here>
```

and this is what I want to do but it not working:

```
target1.PREREQUISITES = file11 file12 file13
target2.PREREQUISITES = file21 file22 file23

$(myDir)%.sfx : $(%.PREREQUISITES)
    <commun recipe here>
```

It always says that there is nothing to do because the target is up to date.

I have the feeling that the problem could be what is done in each make phase, I mean, what is done first the % or $. Should it be working just fine?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks user657267 for your answer, it does work and it gave me a good lead. For those not too familiar with make notice the double dollar sign. I am including my answer here, however, because it still uses the `%` sign that was part of my original question and is working as well as yours. I am using the following solution.

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

$(mydir)%.sfx: $$(%.PREREQUISITES)
    echo $^
```

I just noticed, and be aware of it, that when using a secondary expansion make does not tell you that a **missing prerequisite** has no rule, instead it displays a misleading message saying that there is no rule to make the **target**.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need something like [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion) for this to work, otherwise the expansion of the variable in the prerequisites occurs *before* the pattern is substituted, and you haven't defined a variable called `%.PREREQUISITES`.

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

$(mydir)%.sfx: $$($$*.PREREQUISITES)
    echo $^
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, however I get a secondary undesired effect: if one of the prerequisite files is missing, for instance file12, make complains that there is no rule to make the target, rather than complaining about a lack of rule to make file12.

Comment: It is unfortunate that the make manual does not have an example of a variable used in a prerequisite with a `%` sign. I did see only one example with `%` in a prerequisite but it is not a variable, it is in a function, but it is not clear for me why that example works and mine not. This is what is in the manual: `%.o: $$(addsuffix /%.c,foo bar) foo.h`

Comment: Actually I just tried a test file this way and worked as well as your proposal but I don't understand why: **`$(myDir)%.sfx : $$(%.PREREQUISITES)`** and it has the same side effect as yours: it does not tell you that a prerequisite file is missing.

Answer (score 3):

The second expansion proposed by user657267 works well. GNU make also supports a kind of loop mechanism that you can use to instantiate several rules with very similar forms:

```
target1.PREREQUISITES = file11 file12 file13
target2.PREREQUISITES = file21 file22 file23
TARGETS = target1 target2

# $(1) is a parameter to substitute. The $$ will expand as $.
define MY_rule
$$(myDir)$(1).sfx : $$($(1).PREREQUISITES)
    <same recipe here>
endef
$(foreach target,$(TARGETS),$(eval $(call MY_rule,$(target))))
```

- `foreach` loops over all words in `$(TARGETS)` and assigns the current word to `$(target)`.
- `call` performs an expansion of `MY_rule` where it substitutes `$(1)` with the current value of `$(target)` and `$$` with `$`.
- `eval` instantiates the result of the `call` expansion as a regular rule.

The result of the first iteration of `foreach`, for instance, will be:

```
$(eval $(call MY_rule,target1))
```

The `call` will evaluate as:

```
$(myDir)target1.sfx : $(target1.PREREQUISITES)
    <same recipe here>
```

and `eval` will instantiate it as a rule. **Important**: do not forget that `call` performs a first expansion. So, if your `<same recipe here>` contains `$` symbols, do not forget to double them, unless their expansion by `call` is fine. If your recipe makes use of shell variables, it is even possible that you end up with things like `$$$$var`.

This mechanism is slightly more powerful and generic that the second expansion. It even works with more than one parameter to substitute and with nested loops:

```
target1.PREREQUISITES = file11 file12 file13
target2.PREREQUISITES = file21 file22 file23
TARGETS = target1 target2
DIRS = myDir

# $(1): target
# $(2): directory
define MY_rule
$(2)$(1).sfx : $$($(1).PREREQUISITES)
    <same recipe here>
endef
$(foreach target,$(TARGETS),$(foreach dir,$(DIRS),$(eval $(call MY_rule,$(target),$(dir)))))
```

And you can even embed a `foreach-eval-call` inside a `define-endef`:

```
target1.PREREQUISITES = file11 file12 file13
target2.PREREQUISITES = file21 file22 file23
TARGETS = target1 target2
DIRS = myDir

# $(1): target
# $(2): directory
define MY_rule_1
$(2)$(1).sfx : $$($(1).PREREQUISITES)
    <same recipe here>
endef

# $(1): directory
define MY_rule_2
$$(foreach target,$$(TARGETS),$$(eval $$(call MY_rule_1,$$(target),$(1))))
endef
$(foreach dir,$(DIRS),$(eval $(call MY_rule_2,$(dir))))
```